# Conflict between jQuery conditions

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I have this code

```
    if (winScroll < min_scroll){
         $("header").hide().removeClass("header-vu");

    } else  if (min_scroll < winScroll < max_scroll){
         $("header").show();                  
    } else {
         $("header").addClass("header-vu");                 
    }
```

I don't understand why the third condition (else) isn't expressed if the second (else if) is present.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: min_scroll < winScroll < max_scroll is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (at least, *a* problem) is here:

```
} else  if (min_scroll < winScroll < max_scroll){
```

That boils down to

```
} else  if ((min_scroll < winScroll) < max_scroll){
// Note     ^                      ^
```

The inner `(min_scroll < winScroll)` will be coerced to `0` (if it's false) or `1` (if it's true). So you'll get:

```
} else  if (0 < max_scroll){
```

or

```
} else  if (1 < max_scroll){
```

You probably meant:

```
} else  if (min_scroll < winScroll && winScroll < max_scroll){
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same operand in two operations, you need to do two separate operations:

```
} else  if (min_scroll < winScroll && winScroll < max_scroll) {
```